# what is flow of this program? please enlighten my knowledge

Tags: java, object, static, this

What exactly happens when call obj1.test2(obj2) what values applies in this method? if we are swapping the values what is previous and applied values?please enlighten my knowledge

```
package app4;

public class T 
{
  int i;
  static void test1(T t1, T t2)
  {
    int x = t1.i;
    t1.i = t2.i;
    t2.i = x;
  }
  void test2(T t1)
  {
    int x = t1.i;
    t1.i = this.i;
    this.i = x;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    T obj1 = new T(), obj2 = new T();
    obj1.i = 1;
    obj2.i = 2;
    test1(obj1, obj2);
    System.out.println(obj1.i + "," + obj2.i);
    obj1.test2(obj2);
    System.out.println(obj1.i + "," + obj2.i);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through it using a debugger, you'll get alot more information out of it.

Comment: `x = a; a = b; b = x;` is quite a common pattern. I think you can figure out what it does and why the `x` is needed.

Comment: In fact, debugger is made for this purpose. Use it.

Comment: Is there a particular line at which you don't understand what happens?

Comment: when calling obj1.test2(obj2); confused with the value of t1.i = this.i; what is happening in this case and what happens if i call like obj2.test2(obj2);

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are doing a swap between object values. The only difference is that one method uses two parameters and the other just one. You can follow the comments for a better understanding.

```
public class T 
{
  int i;
  static void test1(T t1, T t2) // t1 = 1, t2 = 2
  {
    int x = t1.i;
    t1.i = t2.i;
    t2.i = x;
  }
  void test2(T t1) // t1 = 1
  {
    int x = t1.i;  
    t1.i = this.i; // 'this' is a keyword in java that is referring to the current object 
    this.i = x;    /* in our case the current object is obj1, and because the values have
                    * been swapped in the first method, this.i = 2 */
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    T obj1 = new T(), obj2 = new T();
    obj1.i = 1;
    obj2.i = 2;
    test1(obj1, obj2); // after returning from this method: obj1 = 2, obj2 = 1
    System.out.println(obj1.i + "," + obj2.i);
    obj1.test2(obj2); // after returning from this method: obj1 = 1, obj2 = 2
    System.out.println(obj1.i + "," + obj2.i);
  }
}
```